# How can I create a graph like this with ggplot in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is this even possible with ggplot?
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCyZN.png)

I tried geom_point(), but I don't think it can work. I also can't find the semi-circle shape.

Comment: But why would you want to?

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use `ggforce::geom_arc_bar` to draw the half circles for which I set `sep=pi`. The rest is a lot of fiddling to put the labels at the right positions.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)
library(showtext)
#> Loading required package: sysfonts
#> Loading required package: showtextdb

showtext_auto()

font_add_google("Roboto Condensed", "roboto")

dat <- data.frame(
  x = 1:5,
  r = c(.143, .321, .176, .129, -.2)
)

col <- "grey75"
scale <- .75
fontsize <- 10

ggplot(dat) +
  geom_arc_bar(
    aes(
      x0 = x, y0 = 0, r0 = 0, r = -scale * sign(r) * sqrt(abs(r)),
      amount = 1
    ),
    stat = "pie", sep = pi, fill = col
  ) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color = col) +
  geom_text(
    aes(x = x, y = sign(r) * .1, label = scales::percent(r)),
    color = "white", size = .8 + fontsize / .pt, family = "roboto"
  ) +
  annotation_custom(
    grob = grid::textGrob(
      label = "Price difference %",
      x = unit(-20, "pt"),
      y = unit(.9, "npc"),
      gp = grid::gpar(col = "white", fontsize = fontsize, fontfamily = "roboto"),
      hjust = 0, vjust = 0
    )
  ) +
  annotation_custom(
    grob = grid::textGrob(
      label = c("% that U.S. is paying more", "% that U.S. is paying less"),
      x = unit(-20, "pt"),
      y = unit(.5, "npc") + unit(c(.37, -.25), "npc"),
      gp = grid::gpar(col = col, fontsize = fontsize * .8, fontfamily = "roboto"),
      hjust = 0, vjust = 1
    )
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(.2, 0, .2, 0)) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0.01, 0.01)) +
  coord_fixed(clip = "off") +
  theme_void() +
  theme(
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "black"),
    plot.margin = margin(0, 11, 0, 11, "pt"),
    axis.ticks.length.y.left = unit(20, "pt")
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, just wow. Where can I learn ggplot?

Comment: Thx @onyambu. There are many good resources on the web. Google `ggplot2 tutorial`. One tutorial I would recommend is from Ced Scherer who does amazing things with ggplot2: https://www.cedricscherer.com/2019/08/05/a-ggplot2-tutorial-for-beautiful-plotting-in-r/. He also taught a ggplot2 workshop at the rstudio::conf: https://www.cedricscherer.com/2022/08/09/2-day-workshop-on-graphic-design-with-ggplot2-at-rstudioconf-2022/. Then there is the ggplot2 book: https://ggplot2-book.org/index.html. And also a workshop from the pkg maintainer on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h29g21z0a68